# Handle Keyboard Done pressed event on Iphone

Tags: iphone, keyboard, key, handle

I am moving my view when a text field is pressed in order to get proper view when keyboard appears. Now, when the Done keyboard button is pressed, I would like to return the view to its initial state. How do I handle an action when the done keyboard button is pressed?

Answer (score 21):

The proper way to do this is to observe to the notifications `UIKeyboardDidShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardDidHideNotification` as detailed in [Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7).

If you want to know when the `Done` button has been pressed, implement

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

In your delegate. It should be called when the return button is pressed. See [API documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldReturn:) for more details.

Answer (score 11):

Make an `IBAction` and connect it to the text field's `didEndOnExit` method. Then within the implementation of this method you should put `[yourTextFieldOutlet resignFirstResponder];`, which will deactivate the text field.

Answer (score 4):

@freespace has it right, this is all you need to do.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Tap the done button and poof, the keyboard is gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know that Done was pressed, you can ask to be told of that control event:

```
[textField addTarget:self
              action:@selector(donePressed)
    forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit];
```

That's the code version of IB's `didEndOnExit`.